How to create a JAR file for a JavaFX Application which opens on double clicking the JAR file
I am currently working on a game in JavaFX.
I have to submit the game as a JAR file.
I have made sure I have a main class that does not extend Application
I tried to create the JAR file using the IntelliJ artifact method and the shade plugin method. Both of the method created a JAR file, but none of them were starting the JavaFX application when I double clicked the JAR file. The JAR file would only run from the terminal with the command java -jar filepath.jar.
The application runs from the terminal, but gives the following warning

com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @66ec91e5'

How do I fix this. I want to be able to start the JavaFX application when I double click the jar file.
I am using OpenJDK 22 and OpenJFX 22.

Only one topic per Question on Stack Overflow. I suggest you edit this Question to focus on one topic. Then post another Question for the other topic.

Before posting here, search Stack Overflow thoroughly.

Create a batch file that runs the command. That's what I do. That's assuming you are using Windows.

If doing java -jar filepath.jar works,
then this is likely not an issue with your code nor the way you packaged it. Do you have *.jar files associated with Java on your computer?

As noted in the artifact packaging documentation for JavaFX page for Idea -> "Packaging a JavaFX application in .jar is possible only with Java 8.".  The JavaFX artifact packaging mechanism in Idea 2024 is obsolete and not built to function correctly with any modern JavaFX version.

You have to "submit the game as a JAR file", so it is an assignment.  If it runs from the command line, ignore the "Unsupported configuration" warning.  A single package jar is not a supported configuration, but if that is the requirement for your assignment, and you have made the app run for JavaFX 22, then you have fulfilled your assignment requirement and don't need to do anything else.

If "opens on double clicking the JAR file" is not a requirement of your assignment, then don't do it, the person you are submitting can run the jar from a command line.  If they asked for an executable jar, they should have the skill to do that.

Double clickable jars are a bad idea and won't work well for this purpose since JavaFX is not included in most modern JDKs.   Use the jpackage tool to make a proper application image or installer.
